# Perl threads don't suspend/ resume

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am using `Thread::Suspend` to start threads from remote modules. Some of the `$subrotine` calls take longer than 30 seconds.

```
my $thr = threads->create(sub {
    capture(EXIT_ANY, $^X, $pathToModule, $subroutine, %arguments)
});
return $thr->tid();
```

My issue is that I am not able to suspend/resume a created thread. Here is the code execute to suspend a thread:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw (capture $EXITVAL EXIT_ANY);
use threads;
use Thread::Suspend; 
use Try::Tiny; 

sub suspendThread {
    my $msg;
    my $threadNumber = shift;

    foreach (threads->list()) {
        if ($_->tid() == $threadNumber) {
            if ($_->is_suspended() == 0) {
                try {
                    # here the execution of the thread is not paused
                    threads->suspend($_);
                } catch {
                    print "error: " . $! . "\n";
                };

                $msg = "Process $threadNumber paused";
            } else {
                $msg = "Process $threadNumber has to be resumed\n";
            }   
        }
    }

    return $msg;
}
```

And this is the code from the module that I load dynamically:

```
sub run {
    no strict 'refs';
    my $funcRef = shift;
    my %paramsRef = @_;
    print &$funcRef(%paramsRef);
}

run(@ARGV);
```

I guess that the problem is that the `sub` passed to the treads constructor calls capture (from `IPC::System::Simple` module). I also tried to create the thread with `my $thr = threads->create(capture(EXIT_ANY, $^X, $pathToModule, $subroutine, %arguments));` Any ideas how to resolve it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why not just use e.g. a semaphore or other IPC to pause a thread?

Comment: What happens when you are "not able to suspend/resume a created thread"?  Do you see the _error_ printed?  What is `$msg`?  Since `capture()` creates at least one child process, what effect do you expect suspending a thread in the parent to have on the child process(es)?

Comment: Tip: `$_->suspend()` looks far less weird than `threads->suspend($_)`

Comment: It is extremely important when asking a question that you not just describe conclusions that you've reached but the evidence that lead you to those conclusions. As @ikegami pointed out, you do not explain why you think your thread didn't get suspended.

Comment: @pilcrow What I mean is that when I start a thread with `capture` and while the process is being executed and I invoke `suspendThread` the process continues and no error is being caught.

Answer (score 3):

These are the threads you have:

```
Parent process                  Process launched by capture
+---------------------+         +---------------------+
|                     |         |                     |
|  Main thread        |         |  Main thread        |
|  +---------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|  |               |  |         |  |               |  |
|  | $t->suspend() |  |         |  |               |  |
|  |               |  |         |  |               |  |
|  +---------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|                     |         |                     |
|  Created thread     |         |                     |
|  +---------------+  |         |                     |
|  |               |  |         |                     |
|  | capture()     |  |         |                     |
|  |               |  |         |                     |
|  +---------------+  |         |                     |
|                     |         |                     |
+---------------------+         +---------------------+
```

You claim the thread you created wasn't suspended, but you have practically no way of determining whether it was suspended or not. After all, `capture` does not print anything or change any external variables. In fact, you have no reason to believe it wasn't suspended.

Now, you might want the program you launched to freeze, but you have not done anything to suspend it or its main thread. As such, it will keep on running<sup>[1]</sup>.

If you wanted to suspend an external process, you could send SIGSTOP to it (and SIGCONT to resume it). For that, you'll need the process's PID. I recommend replacing `capture` with an [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) `pump` loop.

---

1. Well, it will eventually block when it tries to write to STDOUT because the pipe got full because you actually did suspend the thread running `capture`.

Comment: I took a look at `IPC::Run` documentation but I am still confused how to replace `capture` with `pump`. I tried to replace `capture` with `open2` from `IPC::Open2` and the replacement doesn't help

Comment: It should be obvious how to replace `capture` with `run`, and the docs show how `run` is just a `start`+`pump`+`finish`. `$h->signal` can be used to send the signal.

Comment: replacing `capture` with `run` is obvious but replacing `run` with the `start+pump+finish` sequence is not

Comment: Maybe not,  but now you know how because that's literally all there is to it